# what will be eigenvalues of this block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$ A=\begin{pmatrix}
O & C\\C^T & D
\end{pmatrix}$, where $O$ is null matrix of order $2$

$C=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}$, and $D$ is a $0,1$ matrix whose eigenvalues are known.

What can be said about eigenvalues of $A$ in terms of eigenvalues of $D$?

I am aware that eigenvalues of $D$ are interlaced between those of $A$. but here C is also of some special form and $D$ is also $0,1$. So can we say something more?

Comment: In my eyes, the problem is, what happens with the eigenvalues of a graph of order 5, if you add to two different vertices an edge joined to a new vertex. Since, you know the eigenvalues of the original graph, you also know its characteristic polynomial. After that using Sachs's theorem you could compute the number of elementary graphs in the new graph, and to compute the coefficients of its characteristic polynomial.

Comment: What is Sachs's theorem? Can you give some reference please?

Comment: This is the original paper, but maybe you will need papers which are citing it: H. Sachs, Beziehungen zwischen den in einem Graphen enthaltenen Kreisen und seinem
charakteristischen Polynom, Publ. Math. (Debrecen), 11 (1964), 119–134.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the eigenvalue equation
\begin{equation*}
A\mathbf{f}=\lambda \mathbf{f}
\end{equation*}
Write
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{f}=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
\mathbf{f}_{1} \\
\mathbf{f}_{2}
\end{array}
\right)
\end{equation*}
and work things out noting that $C^{T}C$ is the $2\times 2$ identity matrix.
Then you find
\begin{equation*}
D\mathbf{f}_{2}=(\lambda ^{2}+1)\mathbf{f}_{2}
\end{equation*}
so $\mathbf{f}_{2}$ is an eigenvector of $D$, say at the eigenvalue $\mu $.
Then
\begin{equation*}
\mu =\lambda ^{2}+1
\end{equation*}
There are two $\mu $ 's so also two $\lambda $'s.

Edit: Here is the full story.

We split
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{f}=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
\mathbf{f}_{1} \\
\mathbf{f}_{2}
\end{array}
\right)
\end{equation*}
where $\mathbf{f}_{1}$ has two components and $\mathbf{f}_{2}$ three.

\begin{eqnarray*}
A\mathbf{f} &=&\lambda \mathbf{f} \\
0\mathbf{f}_{1}+C\mathbf{f}_{2} &=&\lambda \mathbf{f}_{1} \\
C^{T}\mathbf{f}_{1}+D\mathbf{f}_{2} &=&\lambda \mathbf{f}_{2} \\
\mathbf{f}_{1} &=&\frac{1}{\lambda }C\mathbf{f}_{2} \\
\frac{1}{\lambda }C^{T}C\mathbf{f}_{2}+D\mathbf{f}_{2} &=&\lambda \mathbf{f}
_{2}
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{equation*}
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}%
\right) \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{array}
\right) =\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\end{equation*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{\lambda }\mathbf{f}_{2}+D\mathbf{f}_{2} &=&\lambda \mathbf{f}_{2} \\
D\mathbf{f}_{2} &=&(\lambda ^{2}+1)\mathbf{f}_{2}
\end{eqnarray*}
I do not know what you mean by $D$ is a $0,1$ matrix. It seems it is $
3\times 3$ in which case it has three eigenvalues $\mu _{j}$ with $j=1,2,3$.
Then
\begin{equation*}
\mu _{j}=\lambda _{j}^{2}+1
\end{equation*}
from which $\lambda _{j}^{2}$ follows. In my earlier answer I said that $D$
had two eigenvalues. This must be three.

Comment: Can you explain, how you come to $\begin{equation*}
D\mathbf{f}_{2}=(\lambda ^{2}+1)\mathbf{f}_{2}
\end{equation*}$. Next, by proving $\mu =\lambda ^{2}+1$, what isa the final conclusion we reached at?

Comment: See the added details in my answer.

Comment: Notice that $CC^T=I$, not $C^TC$,  $D$ is of order $5$ and $0,1$ matrix means entries of $D$ are from the set $\{0,1\}$

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will think about it. It may be useful to introduce the spactral decomposition of $D$ and the Feshbach projection formula. I'll come back to this if I find a useful result.